# How can I change a param in url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change my url from:

```
http://my-domain.com/blog/thinking-something-in-hataccess
```

to:

```
http://my-domain.com/article/thinking-something-in-hataccess
```

using htaccess?

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? Also, check out the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), and there are also a lot of rather good [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all of your links already point to `http://my-domain.com/article/thinking-something-in-hataccess`, then you can add this to your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ /article/$1 [L]
```

You may need to tweak the regular expression here to more specifically match what you need. For example, replacing `(.*)` with `([^/]*)` will match `something-something`, but NOT `something/something`.